# drag and drop question

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a list of items, witch i use with the drag and drop effect of jquery ui, to drop in a textarea, this list of items have this form in the html

`<li fieldID="field-1">Some text</li>`

I know that i can get in the event drop, the text associate to the `li` but my question is how can i get the html, or the attribute called `field-id` in the event `droppable`. I tried using this `ui.draggable.html()` but doesn't give me the html only the text.

Also any suggestions to improve my code are also welcome. Thanks.

Here's an example of my code

[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/U97Mg/1/)

Comment: @Dominic Barnes sorry, I modified the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `attr()` function to retrieve the value of an attribute from a jQuery object. Since ui.draggable is a jQuery object wrapping the element being dragged, `ui.draggable.attr('fieldID')` will give you "field-1" for the html you posted.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/Q6use/3/

Answer (score 1):

like Bryan Ross said: http://jsfiddle.net/Q6use/3/